# Fixed Footer, with Overflowing Body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using Bootstrap for a responsively designed web-app, I am looking to replicate the typical mobile-app layout:

`Fixed Navbar` + `Overflowing Body` + `Fixed Footer`

Check out the Smartphone preview (right-side icon) of: http://www.bootply.com/124373

I have the following CSS, which is close, but the fixed footer cuts-off the body - instead of the body scrolling:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

.boxes {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.middle {
  margin-top: 4%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mobile App Format Replication</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container middle">
  <div class="row boxes">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/125"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/125"></div>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="row boxes">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/125"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/125"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Fixed Footer -->
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Fixed Footer Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `position: fixed` on the footer element, and removing the negative margin on the body (instead, use 60px bottom padding instead):

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px;
}
```

See fork here: <kbd>[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/124379)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replicate the mobile app layout, you should try Ratchet: 
http://goratchet.com/

And here are some of the examples: http://goratchet.com/examples/

You can use "Tab bar" to have a fixed footer on there. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.bar-nav~.content{padding-top: 44px;padding-bottom: 44px;}` in your styles.

It's completely done!